# Same query args showing different results order when setting different number of posts

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

This query using the same arguments is returning different posts order:

sample / test codes:

```
// Query 1
$query_args = [
    'post_type' => 'business',
    'showposts' => 8,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'business_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'australia-new-zealand-wantok-specialists',
        ]
    ],
];
$q = new WP_Query($query_args);
foreach( $q->posts as $post ) {
    print_r($post->ID . ' | '. $post->post_title);
}

// Query 2 - same query args, just different number of posts
$query_args['showposts'] = 7;
$q = new WP_Query($query_args);
foreach( $q->posts as $post ) {
    print_r($post->ID . ' | '. $post->post_title);
}

// Query 3 - same query args returning to initial number of posts
$query_args['showposts'] = 8;
$q = new WP_Query($query_args);
foreach( $q->posts as $post ) {
    print_r($post->ID . ' | '. $post->post_title);
}
```

The results are showing different order of posts when changing the showposts/num
e.g:
sample results:

```
=== Query 1 ===
3279 | Matt McLachlan Battlefield Tours
3278 | Virgin Australia Holidays
3277 | Sicklebill Safaris
3276 | P&O Cruises
3275 | Coral Expeditions
3271 | Crooked Compass
3272 | Wild Earth Expeditions
3274 | North Star Cruises

=== Query 2 ===

3279 | Matt McLachlan Battlefield Tours
3276 | P&O Cruises
3277 | Sicklebill Safaris
3278 | Virgin Australia Holidays
3271 | Crooked Compass
3272 | Wild Earth Expeditions
3275 | Coral Expeditions

=== Query 3 ===

3279 | Matt McLachlan Battlefield Tours
3278 | Virgin Australia Holidays
3277 | Sicklebill Safaris
3276 | P&O Cruises
3275 | Coral Expeditions
3271 | Crooked Compass
3272 | Wild Earth Expeditions
3274 | North Star Cruises
```

https://prnt.sc/7vSL02uBxApC

Notice the 2nd query it is showing a different order of posts,
added a 3rd query to test consistency of the first query.

This happens when using "tax_query", without tax_query, everything is working as expected, returning same results order.

I don't understand why this is happening, do you guys have any idea on what's happening here?